# HTTP status code to status message

Tags: python, http, http-status-codes

I'm looking for a way, in Python, to get the HTTP message from the status code. Is there a way that is better than building the dictionary yourself?

Something like:

```
>>> print http.codemap[404]
'Not found'
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Python 2.7, the [httplib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html) module has what you need:

```
>>> import httplib
>>> httplib.responses[400]
'Bad Request
```

Constants are also available:

```
httplib.responses[httplib.NOT_FOUND]
httplib.responses[httplib.OK]
```

Update

[@shao.lo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/820013/shao-lo) added a useful comment bellow. The [http.client](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html) module can be used:

```
# For Python 3 use
import http.client
http.client.responses[http.client.NOT_FOUND]
```

Comment: For python3 use

`import http.client`
and
`http.client.responses[http.client.NOT_FOUND]`

Answer (score 13):

This problem is solved in Python 3.5 onward. Python `http` library has a built-in module called [HTTPStatus](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.html#http.HTTPStatus).

The HTTP status components such as numeric code (value), the phrase, and the description are all available from attributes.

The documentation provides this example:

```
>>> from http import HTTPStatus
>>> HTTPStatus.OK
HTTPStatus.OK
>>> HTTPStatus.OK == 200
True
>>> HTTPStatus.OK.value
200
>>> HTTPStatus.OK.phrase
'OK'
>>> HTTPStatus.OK.description
'Request fulfilled, document follows'
>>> list(HTTPStatus)
[HTTPStatus.CONTINUE, HTTPStatus.SWITCHING_PROTOCOLS, ...]
```

Answer (score 7):

Python 3:

You could use [`HTTPStatus(<error-code>).phrase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.html#http.HTTPStatus) to obtain the description for a given code value.  E.g. like this:

```
try:
    response = opener.open(url, 
except HTTPError as e:
    print(f'In func my_open got HTTP {e.code} {HTTPStatus(e.code).phrase}')
```

Would give for example:

```
In func my_open got HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type
```

Which answers the question. However a much more direct solution can be obtained from `HTTPError.reason`:

```
try:
    response = opener.open(url, data)
except HTTPError as e:
    print(f'In func my_open got HTTP {e.code} {e.reason}')
```

Comment: @JSTL It was, but this answer gives usage examples.

Answer (score -1):

A 404 error indicates that the page may have been moved or taken offline. It differs from a 400 error which would indicate pointing at a page that never existed.

Comment: I changed the message